# Facing an issue with the click outside condition in a React modal

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using `contains` to determine whether a click occurred outside the modal window and, based on that, I'm closing the modal.

The problem is as follows: even when the condition for the form check `isFormNotEmpty` returns `true`, the click event handler always executes the `else` branch, logging "LOOSER!". I'm certain that the value of `isFormNotEmpty` is indeed `true` in this case.

```
const handleClickOutside: EventListener = (event) => {
        if (modalRef.current && !modalRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
            if (isFormNotEmpty) {
                console.log("SUCCESS!");
                const shouldClose = window.confirm("Some form fields are not empty. Do you really want to close the modal?");
                if (shouldClose) {
                    hideModal();
                }
            } else {
                console.log("LOOSER!");
                hideModal();
            }
        }
    };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window) {
      window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
    }
  }, []);
```

There is a Modal

```
{isModalOpen && (
        <div
          className={`fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 flex justify-center items-center z-50 overflow-y-scroll ${
            className && className
          }`}>
          <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-black opacity-50"></div>
          <div
            className="relative w-full max-w-2xl max-h-full tablet-max:px-5"
            ref={modalRef}>
            <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-whiteText">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between p-4 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                {lottie && <Lottie animationData={lottie} className="w-12" />}
                <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">{title}</h3>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-primary hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center"
                  onClick={hideModal}>
                  <svg
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    className="w-5 h-5"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                      fillRule="evenodd"
                      d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                      clipRule="evenodd"></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="p-2 space-y-6">{children}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
```

My objective is to close the modal when a click occurs outside its boundaries, except when certain form fields are not empty.

Comment: It's a custom modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `isFormNotEmpty` in the dependencies array of the `useEffect`, like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (window) {
      window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
    }
}, [isFormNotEmpty]);
```

As otherwise, you will always be referencing the initial value of `isFormNotEmpty` in your event handler, as it's registered in memory on the first render, and never updated.